# android draw pin on google map

Tags: android, google-maps

I have created googlemap in my android application. Now i want to draw pin at my location.

This is my code for that:-

```
public class GooglemapActivity extends MapActivity {
private List<Overlay> mapOverlays;
private Drawable drawable;
private MyOverlay itemizedOverlay;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    MapView mMapView;
    mMapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    mMapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mapOverlays = mMapView.getOverlays();
    drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.c_map_pin_blue);
    itemizedOverlay = new MyOverlay(drawable);
    GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint((int) 26.863966000000000,
            (int) 75.766938300000000);

    itemizedOverlay.addItem(point, "Quippelin", "0");
    mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);

}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
}
```

and this is my another class:-

```
public class MyOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> {
private ArrayList<OverlayItem> overlayItemList = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();

public MyOverlay(Drawable marker) {
    super(boundCenterBottom(marker));
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    populate();
}

public void addItem(GeoPoint p, String title, String snippet) {
    OverlayItem newItem = new OverlayItem(p, title, snippet);
    overlayItemList.add(newItem);
    populate();
}

@Override
protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return overlayItemList.get(i);
}

@Override
public int size() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return overlayItemList.size();
}

@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);
    // boundCenterBottom(marker);
}
}
```

my map is displaying correctly but my pin is not displaying, please help me to findout the mistake which i have done.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything looks good except your point is way "off".

Your calculation is wrong as your pin should be displayed near coordinates 0,0. Try that:

```
GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint((int) (26.863966 * 1E6), (int) (75.7669383 * 1E6));
```

Reason: your (int) cast results in 26 and 75 which should be somewhere near the north pole. Check the documentation:

> Constructs a GeoPoint with the given latitude and longitude, measured in microdegrees (degrees * 1E6).

Answer (score 0):

I used this code to resolve my problem.

```
  double mLatitude = 26.863966000000000;
  double mLongtitude = 75.766938300000000;
  GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint((int) (mLatitude * 1E6),(int) (mLongtitude * 1E6));
```

Now its working fine.

and answer of WarrenFaith is also correct.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with your point. Try these points.

```
GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint((int) 19240000,(int) -99120000);
```